# How to handle a large object size in c++ when doing image/video processing

Tags: c++, opencv, object, size

I am using openCV to parse videos with >10000 frames. On each frame, I need to detect up to 10 markers, save their position in the current image and calculate and save an object's position based on the markers along with some more primitive type variables for each frame. I do not need to keep the image itself in the form of an openCV matrix once my calculation is done.

My idea for this was a state machine object that would contain a vector of *n* frame objects (those contain the markers positions in the specific frame along with some more data) and a vector of up to 10 marker objects (that contain the marker's ID along with their real world position) to load the next frame, detect the markers, run calculations, ... .

However, the state machine object's size would be at least 697 600 (sizeof state machine object at roughly 10 000 frames).

I am wondering what the best practice would be in this case. Is it bad practice to have objects this large in general? Is it acceptable to have an object of this size on the heap? Should I save each frame's data straight to a file (and read it out for a specific frame later on) or will this slow down the program too much with a large amount of read and write accesses? Are there other better suited ways for my case?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I see nothing wrong with it. If the number of frames is constant and the number of markers is usually close to 10 an array of arrays might be more efficient. Maybe you can also make the datastructure itself more compact (using shorts instead of ints and making sure there is no padding)

Comment: 64kB of memory should be enough for *any* program.